# I need help converting a UITextField from string to Int

Tags: swift, xcode

I have made a simple project which sends data from one view controller to a second.

It works for a string, but I now want to change the code so it can multiply the UITextField answer by 10 and output it to the label in the Second ViewController. I know that I just need to change the string to Int but I've tried lots of things and nothing has worked.

I know there must be some simple way that I'm overlooking.

Any help is appreciated.

ViewController

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    
    @IBOutlet var EnterNumber: UITextField!
        
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        EnterNumber.delegate = self
        
        
    }
    
        
        
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let VC2 : ViewController2 = segue.destination as! ViewController2
        VC2.LabelText = EnterNumber.text!
    }


}

extension ViewController : UITextFieldDelegate{
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }
}
```

ViewController 2

```
import UIKit

class ViewController2: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet var Label: UILabel!
    
    var LabelText = String()
    
    
    
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        
        Label.text = LabelText
    }
    


}
```

[ViewController 1 and 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0UEz.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let VC2: ViewController2 = segue.destination as! ViewController2
    if let integerValue = Int(EnterNumber.text!) {
        VC2.LabelText = "\(integerValue * 10)"
    } else {
        print("\(EnterNumber.text!) could not be converted to an integer.")
    }
}
```

Comment: That gives the error 'Expression type () is ambiguous without more context', and, 'String interpolation can only appear inside a string literal'

Comment: My bad, I missed the double quotes on both sides of that. Check now.